How to enable desktop notifications for Outlook Web? Notifications are not showing
I have Outlook Web open in one of Chrome's tabs. I want to get a visible reminder popping up in Windows like in the system tray or a toast during any app I am using.
I am not getting such notifications. Only a reminder toast inside of Outlook web.
How do I enable the desktop notifications? I see some documentation to enable 'Desktop notification' but I don't see this option.
I have enabled notifications in Outlook web and Chrome.



is the page on an outlook.office.com url when you are on the page you want to recieve notifications on? Ms changes domains all the time, and some application components are not always on the same domain. just a thought.

I don't understand your question. One tab is open on the calendar page and it's not the tab that has focus in the browser. I want to get a notification in Windows regardless of what Windows app I am using at the time the notification should come up.

my point was that the configuration images you displayed only do anything when you are on a url that matches that domain exactly.  Personally I've never seen desktop notifications from browsers work reliably.

I have a tab opened on the calendar. Doesn't that mean I am on the url? Of course my browser is not going to have that tab focused all day long. Looks like I might have to develop my own notifier.

In the first screenshot click on those arrows there's a setting to display in outlook, in browser or none.. Pick the In browser option and outlook will start displaying notifications in windows

You want to expand that section under Email/Calendar and pick the notification option that sends it to the browser

